# How to export data from For loop in text file?

Tags: export

I'm new in Mathematica and I am trying to write numbers from 1 to 10 in txt file. But "Null" is everything that is written in my file. The code is:

```
Export["C:\\Users\\Sealy\\Desktop\\list.txt",
       For[k = 1, k <= 10, k++, Print[List[k]]]]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/193)?

Comment: @stevenvh It's the [name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wayne_Gacy) that halted me. =:-O

Answer (score 9):

Here are some variants to achieve what you want using various notations and avoiding the use of the dreaded `For` loop.

**Exporting as strings**

Standard notation:

```
Export[ "/tmp/10.txt", Range@10]
```

Infix notation:

```
 "/tmp/10.txt"~Export~Range@10
```

**Exporting in Mathematica format**

Save as a list, so it can easily be read back into mathematica using `Get`.

```
Range@10 >> "/tmp/10.mma"
```

Read it back in using the short form of the function `Get`:

```
<< "/tmp/10.mma"
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

**Why you might not want a `For` loop**

For loops aren't used very much in Mathematica as there are more efficient ways to approach the need to repeat computations. Lists are fundamental to what Mathematica does and in conjunction with other techniques such as `Map` make `For` loops and `Do`,`While` redundant.

**Map**

The `Map` function, shortform `/@`, which can apply a function to a list of items.

`Sin/@{1,2,3,4,5,6}` - > {Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4], Sin[5], Sin[6]}

**Listability**

The ability of functions to apply themselves to a list,

`Sin[{1,2,3,4,5,6}]` -> {Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4], Sin[5], Sin[6]}

**Functions can Return Lists**

( Here we use the short form of function invocation, `f@arg` instead of `f[arg]` )

`Range@6` -> {1,2,3,4,5,6}

and

`Sin@Range@6`-> {Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4], Sin[5], Sin[6]}

Answer (score 3):

Recommendation: Read up on `Table`, `Range` etc. . Press <kbd>F1</kbd> often!

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test.txt", Range[10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(* Initiate an empty List *)
list = {};
(* Use AppendTo in order to add  the entries in each iteration *)
For[k = 1, k <= 10, k++, list = AppendTo[list, k]];
(* Then export the List *)
Export["C:\Users\Sealy\Desktop\list.txt", list]
```

However the simplest Mathematica way to do it will be by calling `Table`

```
list=Table[k,{k,1,10}];
Export["C:\Users\Sealy\Desktop\list.txt", list]
```

BR

Comment: `Table[k,{k,1,10}]` is waaay too long. `Range[10]` does exactly the same.

Comment: @stevenvh this was meant to introduce the very commonplace and still powerful MMA function `Table` to the OP as he claims to be a novice. I thought of explainign him a bit more in detail but image_dioctor has already done that...

Answer (score 1):

`Print` is used for it's side  effect (which is printing to the screen) but it returns `Null`. Also the `For` loop returns `Null`

Try this:

```
lst = {};
For[k = 1, k <= 10, k++, AppendTo[lst, {k}]]
lst
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}} *)
Export["C:\Users\Sealy\Desktop\list.txt", lst]
```

Comment: I have managed to export lists and to import them in Mathematica using ways you all suggested. but now, I have to sum two elements of those imported lists (for example, for {d_1, d_2, d_3} I have to find sums d_1+d_2, d_2+d_3 and d_1+d_3 and to deal with those sums that satisfy some conditions). How can I do that? I saw a lot of examples that use "#" as a variable of a list but I think I cannot use that two times (For example, If[#+#], Print[12] does not make sense)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @WayneGacy, that's a new question. `Function[in, in + RotateLeft[in]][{d1, d2, d3}]`

Comment: Ups, thank you!